# Base de datos no guarda datos de registro desde formulario PHP en mi tabla de MySQL

Tags: php, html, base-de-datos

tardes o noches. Tengo una especie de problema con PHP y MySQL (phpMyAdmin). Estoy programando una página web donde se requiere el registro de usuario. Pero cuando se ingresan los datos en las cajas correspondientes, no me manda nada. No me manda errores ni fallas fatales, pero no registra los datos en la base de datos. Este es el  del registro (signup.php).

```
<form method="post" action="signup.php">
<?php include('errors.php'); ?>
                                <div class="content-container" style="padding: 80px;">
                                    <div class="signup-container">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Nombre de usuario" value="" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password_1" placeholder="Contraseña" value="" />
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password_2" placeholder="Confirma tu contraseña" value="" />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Correo electrónico" value="" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="submit" class="btnSubmit log-button" name="log-user" value="Ingresar" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

Este es el código donde hago el query, defino variables, etc.

```
<?php
session_start();

//Variables 
$username = "";
$password = "";
$email = "";
$errors = array();

//Conexión a la base de datos
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'metagg_db');

//Registro de usuario
if (isset($_POST['log_user'])){
    // Recive todos los datos ingresados desde el <form>
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
    $password_1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password_1']);
    $password_2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password_2']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']);

    // Validacion: se encarga de que los datos de el <form> esten correctamente ingresados

    if(empty($username)) { 
        array_push($errors, "Se requiere el nombre de usuario.");
    }
    if(empty($email)) { 
        array_push($errors, "Se requiere su email.");
    }
    if(empty($password_1)) { 
        array_push($errors, "Se requiere una contraseña.");
    }
    if($password_1 != $password_2) {
        array_push($errors, "Las contraseñas no coinciden.");
    }

    //Verifica si ya existe un usuario con el mismo nombre de usuario o email en la base de datos
    $user_check_query = "SELECT * FROM mgg_users WHERE username='$username' OR email='$email' LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $user_check_query);
    $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    if ($user) { //Si el usuario existe
        if ($user['username'] === $username) {
            array_push($errors, "El nombre de usario ya existe.");
        }

        if ($user['email'] === $email) {
            array_push($errors, "Ese email ya esta usado por otra cuenta.");
        }
    }
    // Finalmente, registramos al usuario si no hay nungun error 
    if(count($errors) == 0) {
        $password = md5($password_1);//encripta la contraseña antes de registrarla en la base de datos

        $query = "INSERT INTO mgg_users (username, email, password)VALUES('$username', '$email', '$password')";
        mysqli_query($db, $query);
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['succes'] = "Te has registrado con exito.";
        header('location: signup.php');
    }
}
```

Como dije antes, al ingresar los datos necesarios en las cajas de registro, y al revisar la tabla de registros (mgg_users), no muestra nada.

Comment: Me parece que el problema esta en la primera condicional (el primer if). Debido a que los valores de los input de tipo submit no se envian en el POST

Comment: ¿Entonces GET?.

Comment: No. Seria cuestion de cambiar el if. Te pondre un ejemplo.

Comment: CUando dices que no manda errores, ¿ya revisaste que el log de PHP tampoco haya generado nada relacionado?

Answer (score 0):

El condicional `if (isset($_POST['log_user']))` espera el valor de un input tipo submit. Pero este no se envian en el POST y al no recibir nada siempre da falso.

```
//Variables 
$username = "";
$password = "";
$email = "";
$errors = array();

//Conexión a la base de datos
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'metagg_db');

//AQUI CAMBIAMOS EL IF PARA VALIDAR SI EXISTE EL METODO POST
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){
    // Recive todos los datos ingresados desde el <form>
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
    $password_1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password_1']);
    $password_2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password_2']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']);

    // Validacion: se encarga de que los datos de el <form> esten correctamente ingresados

    if(empty($username)) { 
        array_push($errors, "Se requiere el nombre de usuario.");
    }
    if(empty($email)) { 
        array_push($errors, "Se requiere su email.");
    }
    if(empty($password_1)) { 
        array_push($errors, "Se requiere una contraseña.");
    }
    if($password_1 != $password_2) {
        array_push($errors, "Las contraseñas no coinciden.");
    }

    //Verifica si ya existe un usuario con el mismo nombre de usuario o email en la base de datos
    $user_check_query = "SELECT * FROM mgg_users WHERE username='$username' OR email='$email' LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $user_check_query);
    $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    if ($user) { //Si el usuario existe
        if ($user['username'] === $username) {
            array_push($errors, "El nombre de usario ya existe.");
        }

        if ($user['email'] === $email) {
            array_push($errors, "Ese email ya esta usado por otra cuenta.");
        }
    }
    // Finalmente, registramos al usuario si no hay nungun error 
    if(count($errors) == 0) {
        $password = md5($password_1);//encripta la contraseña antes de registrarla en la base de datos

        $query = "INSERT INTO mgg_users (username, email, password)VALUES('$username', '$email', '$password')";
        mysqli_query($db, $query);
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['succes'] = "Te has registrado con exito.";
        header('location: signup.php');
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias, pero sigue sin enviar ningún dato a mysql. Ya probé con un projecto de prueba y ligero, donde solo envia datos a la base y ya. Pero tampoco envía nada, ni muestra ningun error, nada, literalmente.